# Liquid simulation sees obstacles' rotation correctly but not their location

Tags: fluid-simulation

I'm having a problem with a simulation, where an obstacle and an outflow are being moved by a parenting relation to an empty, and some fluid should be interacting with them.

The obstacle is a glass-shaped one and should retain the liquid within itself.

However, this happens:

(re-baked at very low resolution, but it happens exactly the same with 280 subdivisions)

[image]

It looks like the rotations are followed correctly, but not the locations.

Any idea how to make the simulation engine see the actual position/rotation of the obstacles?

---

**Edit**: I've made a minimal working file with my issue. It's particularly frustrating: I've recreated every single piece of the simulation but to no luck! It looks like that file is compromised but I can't understand why!

[image]

(It requires baking, but it should take only a few seconds on most computers)

Comment: maybe parrent the liquid to the glass, you might give it a try

Comment: That would double the rotation. Also, it makes little sense to move the domain during the simulation. Anyway, I've tried and it doesn't work. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 5):

[image: example]

Curious about the problem, I set it up myself, but a bit simpler.
The cause is that your glass is too thin walled. Upon closer inspection I saw that at the start it already slips through the bottom.

So I created a thick cup for the water and then you see it stays contained. Because you wouldn't like to create such thick glass, what you could do is create a helper object that has the same inner dimension as your glass, but with thicker walls. In the outliner you disable the render output for this object (so that it won't render), but it will contribute to the backing of your fluid.

*) notice that it's not the best GIF, as I am kind of new to creating GIFs.

**update 1**
Ok usually the above is the case with fluids, but in this file more was going on. Some of the objects had non applied scales (ctrl+a) all objects where parrented to a bezier. I removed it and it behaved right. Though then ofcourse the cup wasnt moving. At least it showed your walls where thick enough. So i went to frame 0 and in 3d view while selecting the cup press i Select "loc rot" skip a few frames (best do this in Right or left View), then move cup up , rotate slightly over x axis (R+x) skip some frames again move cup towards the bin rotate some more. press i loc rot again.
So with "i" +locrot you split up the movement in parts, and you can even control how smooth the motion goes between each "i"+locrot in the graph editor where one can adjust for smooth movements. 
Here is the fixed version :

**Update two**
There is another way to fix your blend file, but the result wont be as good as compared to update 1, you'll have to apply scales to your objects first.
Next for the cup under volume initialization there is an option "export animated mesh", the solver works a bit different (and its not looking as good as update 1), its rarely used. Often used when combined with armatured meshes, i'm not sure why you had this small bezier cube, for such simple motions i wouldnt use bezier curves but go for update one. Just compare how few i+locrot i had to do as compared to the many nodes in grapheditor for your object (that might be a close match to something your not showing here, but tuning that many key frames isnt handy).

update 1 in action :
[image]

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's not the OP's problem (or at least not their *only* problem). Looking at the OP's animation in the question, you can clearly see that the liquid is being constrained by *something* that rotates together with the glass, even after it is no longer actually *in* the glass.

Comment: Yes, Ilmari is right, this doesn't answer my question. The problem doesn't depend on the thickness of the obstacles, as it also happens at way higher resolutions.

Comment: I downloaded yur file now, there might be some more strange things.

Comment: I downloaded yur file now, there might be some more strange things. If you would start clean you get what i made. You have scaling applied to the domain (ctrl+a), another problem i see is the bezier curve you used to animate it. I removed the bezier curve parent from the fluid and from the cup.
Then it started to work, even your file. To get the same movement i'll explain in my main answer ok.